# Navigate back in Lightswitch (HTML5) on iOS 7 devices

Tags: ios, html, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

i'm having an issue with my Lightswitch (html5)  app on iOS7 devices. When i hit the back button all i see is the loading gif and nothing responds. on all other devices (including iOS6) are fine.

i had built another app that used jquerymobile and had an issue with the back button, but i added the code

$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

and it starting working. but its not working with my Lightswitch app.

Has anyone else run into this? is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to not be a Lightswitch issue, it seems that iOS7 has issues with appcache files (it was a very misleading bug :/ ), when i removed the app cache and cleared my cache, it worked fine.